# Configure accents for vim in cmder

Tags: vim, cmder

I'm having problems to get accents work in `vim` under `cmder`. I open `vim` and try to write an accented letter like "á" or "ñ" and it does not render anything, but non-accented characters are written. My `.vimrc` contains the following:

```
" Setting some decent VIM settings for programming

syntax on
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set encoding=utf-8

" Show EOL type and last modified timestamp, right after the filename
set statusline=%<%F%h%m%r\ [%{&ff}]\ (%{strftime(\"%H:%M\ %d/%m/%Y\",getftime(expand(\"%:p\")))})%=%l,%c%V\ %P

"------------------------------------------------------------------------------
" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")
    "Set UTF-8 as the default encoding for commit messages
    autocmd BufReadPre COMMIT_EDITMSG,git-rebase-todo setlocal fileencodings=utf-8

    "Remember the positions in files with some git-specific exceptions"
    autocmd BufReadPost *
      \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
      \           && expand("%") !~ "COMMIT_EDITMSG"
      \           && expand("%") !~ "ADD_EDIT.patch"
      \           && expand("%") !~ "addp-hunk-edit.diff"
      \           && expand("%") !~ "git-rebase-todo" |
      \   exe "normal g`\"" |
      \ endif

      autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.patch set filetype=diff
      autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.diff set filetype=diff

      autocmd Syntax diff
      \ highlight WhiteSpaceEOL ctermbg=red |
      \ match WhiteSpaceEOL /\(^+.*\)\@<=\s\+$/

      autocmd Syntax gitcommit setlocal textwidth=74
endif " has("autocmd")
```

and it's located in `%CMDERFOLDER%/config/.vimrc`. Also in the same folder is placed `.bashrc` with the following content:

```
export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
```

The output of `:set encoding?` is `encoding=utf-8`. If I launch `bash` inside `cmder` and then `vim`, accented characters work as expected but I'd rather not use `bash` directly.

How can I configure vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using `bash` even though I said I'd rather not use `bash`. The reason to not use `bash` was given because I thought it would treat my windows file system differently and I didn't want to launch `bash` manually, but bash can be set to be the default terminal (also, bash has the advantage of supporting command evaluation with backticks (i.e `command muyargument`).

To do this, go to `Settings > Startup` and under `Specified named task` select `{bash ::bash}` and restart `cmder`. It should suffice. If the task does not exist, go to `Settings > Startup > Tasks` and click on `+`, set the task name, enable the option `Default task for new console` and `Taskbar jump lists`. Last, in the `Commands` input, set the following value:

```
cmd /c "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash --login -i"
```

Restart `cmder` and vim should work with accented characters, if your `.vimrc` is set to the values in my question